# how to include module for MiniTest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I have a class `Company` that `include GrowthRate`.

#### models/company.rb

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  include GrowthRate
end
```

In the `growth_rate.rb`, I add some methods for `Array`.

#### models/company/growth_rate.rb

```
module Company::GrowthRate
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
end

module Company::GrowthRate::Array
  def growth_rate
    # calculate growth rate
  end
end

class Array
  include Company::GrowthRate::Array
end
```

And I want to test the method of Array by MiniTest.

#### test/models/company/growth_rate_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class CompanyTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  include Company::GrowthRate
  test 'test for adjusted_growth_rate' do
    array = [1, 0.9]
    Array.stub :growth_rate, 1 do
      # assert_equal
    end
  end
end
```

But the test ends up with a name error.

```
NameError: undefined method `growth_rate' for `Company::GrowthRate::Array'
```

How can I include the method for MiniTest?

#### test/test_helper.rb

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'
require 'minitest/mock'
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all
end
```

Comment: Are you testing the `growth_rate` method? If so, why is it stubbed?

Comment: Sorry, the test is for `def adjusted_growth_rate`, so that I want to stub `growth_rate`. I changed the question.

Comment: Have you tried including:  `require 'test_helper'`? Also, what are the contents of test/test_helper.rb?

Comment: Yes, I'm require `test_helper` and I added the content of it in my question.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use the `ActiveSupport` included block.

For your example, I imagine it can't find the method b/c you're not requiring that file anywhere.

```
module PolymorphicTest
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    test 'some cool polymorphic test' do
      assert private_helper_method
    end


    private

    def private_helper_method
      # do stuff
    end
  end
end
```

Minitest also doesn't autoload these, so you'll need to make sure they're included in a `require` in each test *or* in the test_helper.

If you need me to break this down more, please ask.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to move the `models/company/growth_rate.rb` into app/model/concerns folder with filename = 'growth_rate.rb'

then don't use Company class to prevent conflict class name

```
module GrowthRate
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  # ...
end
```

Now you can include it to your Company model

then create array.rb file in the config/initializers folder which contains

```
class Array
  def growth_rate
    # calculate growth rate
  end
end
```

this file will loaded only once by rails, it's good to adding custom method to Array class if you want to

now you can remove `include Company::GrowthRate` from test/models/company/growth_rate_test.rb

Comment: I used to use `concerns` folder, but it mix up all concerns files so that I found somewhere like now. There is no class name conflict. And I add a new method like this so that I can easily follow stacktrace when error happens.